# I need to wrap every 4 wordpress posts in a div

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a div to wrap every four posts in the wordpress loop. So it would be like

```
<div>
four posts
</div>
<div>
four posts
</div>
```

my current code is this

```
<?php 
        $i = 0;
        $wrap_div = "<div class='frak'>";
            if ( have_posts() ) {
               echo $wrap_div;
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="wine-section">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="wine-info">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?></a>
                <?php the_meta(); ?>
            </div><!-- /wine-info -->
            <div class="c"></div>
        </div><!-- /wine-section -->

        <?php       
                if ($i % 4 == 0) { echo "</div>" . $wrap_div; }
                } // end while
            } // end if
            $i++;
        ?>
```

This code wraps every post individually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing `$i` outside the `while` loop, so inside it `$i` will always be `==0` and thus `$i % 4 == 0`.

Move `$i++;` before `} // end while`.

However, you should also change your condition to `$i % 4 == 3`, because `$i % 4 == 0` evaluates to `true` in the very first iteration (`$i=0`) and will produce an initial `<div>` with only one post.

Alternatively, you could keep your condition as it is, and:

- either start with `$i=1` instead of `0`
- or move `$i++` right after `while`.

Now, when you have an exact multiple of 4 posts, an extra, empty `<div>` will appear at the end. That's because you're assuming that, when a `<div>` closes, another one should automatically open. That's not always the case.

Assuming that you have chosen the `$i % 4 == 3` solution above, and that you already have a `echo '</div>';` after the `while` loop, change your condition to `if(($i % 4 == 3)&& have_posts())`.

Comment: This worked somewhat, and makes a lot of sense. I changed my code and now it has 3 divs instead of 2. The first div has one post, then the next one has 4, and the last one has 3. Is my increment wrong?

Comment: Works, thanks! But now I've got a 3rd div at the end, it's empty but still there. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

As geomagas pointed out - you are incrementing the variable outside of the loop. Then `0 % 4 == 0` does evaluate to true - that's because when you divide 0 by 4, you get 0. In order to get around this situation, you need one more rule.

Also don't forget that with your current code if the total amount of posts is for instance 12, you will have one empty "frak" div at the end of your posts.

```
<?php 
    $i = 0;
    $wrap_div = "<div class='frak'>";
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            // Grab the total posts that are being displayed
            $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
            echo $wrap_div;
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post(); ?>
                <div class="wine-section">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <div class="wine-info">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?></a>
                        <?php the_meta(); ?>
                    </div><!-- /wine-info -->
                    <div class="c"></div>
                </div><!-- /wine-section -->
                <?php 
                // Is this a fourth post? If so, make sure it is not the last post?
                if ( $i % 4 == 0 && $i != 0 && ( $i + 1 ) != $total_posts ) {
                    echo '</div>' . $wrap_div;
                }
                $i ++;
            } // end while
            // Close the $wrap_div
            echo '</div>';
        } // end if
?>
```

As you can see the `if` statement that prints the closing tag and the new wrap is more complex now. 
It makes sure that $i is not 0(meaning it's still the first post) and that $i + 1 does not equal the total amount of posts displayed(for that case we close after the `while()` loop).

If you're wondering why we're closing after the `while()` loop - simply because your posts might not always be exactly multiple on 4(I'm not sure about the correct translation to English here) - and if that's case and you don't close your div after the while loop - you'll have troubles.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! I felt like I was about to lose my mind, then I came across this! :)