# Wrap every three WordPress posts in div

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to wrap every three posts in a new row (div) with a total of nine posts on a page. There's an empty row at the end. I thought this ([I need to wrap every 4 wordpress posts in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640179/i-need-to-wrap-every-4-wordpress-posts-in-a-div)) would work, but I have more posts on pages 2, 3, 4, etc. Below is a simplified version of my code. $i = 1.

```
<div class="row">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="column">
        </div>

        <?php if ($i % 3 == 0 ) : ?>

            </div> <!-- .row -->
            <div class="row">

        <?php endif; $i++; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div> <!-- .row -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this post (https://www.nosegraze.com/display-wordpress-posts-2-3-columns/) to solve my problem.

$i = 0;

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ( $i == 0 ) : ?>

        <div class="row">

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="column">
    </div> <!-- .column -->

    <?php
        $i++;
        if( $i == 3 ) :
        $i = 0; ?>

        </div> <!-- .row -->

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if ( $i > 0 ) : ?>

    </div> <!-- .row -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get_next_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) to check whether next post exists or not.

```
<?php if ($i % 3 == 0 ) : ?>
</div> <!-- .row -->
<?php
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
        <div class="row">
    <?php endif; ?>
```